# Issue in running web projects in netbeans

Tags: glassfish-4.1

I am running Netbeans 8.1 and having trouble with the Glassfish 4.1.1 server. Earlier, it was working fine for all projects however suddenly it stopped working for all the projects. Whenever I am trying to run a web project, I am getting this popup:
[image]

The username is admin and password is blank

```
server log:
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Oct 16, 2016 12:10:10 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Oct 16, 2016 12:10:10 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Oct 16, 2016 12:10:10 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Oct 16, 2016 12:10:11 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/Users/username/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@3e2e334f in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Users/username/GlassFish_Server/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Users/username/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Users/username/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Users/username/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (33,784ms), startup services(1,787ms), total(35,571ms)
Severe:   Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:237)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@626d3eb9 from service registry.
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@626d3eb9 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@4c5a2baf.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Info:   Shutdown procedure finished
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
We are in non-embedded mode, so org.glassfish.main.core.glassfish [107] has nothing to do.
[2016-10-16T12:10:44.351-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244090] [timeMillis: 1476634244351] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:44.354-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244090] [timeMillis: 1476634244354] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:44.585-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244087] [timeMillis: 1476634244585] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:44.591-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244087] [timeMillis: 1476634244591] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:44.605-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244087] [timeMillis: 1476634244605] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:44.821-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244099] [timeMillis: 1476634244821] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:44.915-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244090] [timeMillis: 1476634244915] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.480-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244099] [timeMillis: 1476634245480] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.481-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244087] [timeMillis: 1476634245481] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.754-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244099] [timeMillis: 1476634245754] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.769-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1476634244099] [timeMillis: 1476634245769] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.867-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1476634245867] [levelValue: 800] [[
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (33,784ms), startup services(1,787ms), total(35,571ms)]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.868-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00019] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1476634245868] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:237)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.967-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00092] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=Thread-11] [timeMillis: 1476634245967] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server shutdown initiated]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.980-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00028] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=Thread-11] [timeMillis: 1476634245980] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@626d3eb9 from service registry.]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.977-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1476634245977] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@626d3eb9 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@4c5a2baf.]]
[2016-10-16T12:10:45.984-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1476634245984] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FileMonitoring shutdown]]
```

Even after killing the process at port 8080, I am getting error for Glassfish username and password

Comment: please post the error log here.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed any web servers or anything before this error is coming, and verify this server ports are allocated to any other applications.
If yes try to uninstall and restart the system.

Comment: I haven't installed any web server and yes I have removed and added the Glassfish server again but same issue

Comment: java.net.BindException: Address already in use, because of this you are getting this exception

Comment: That process I already killed, but still not able to run the server

Comment: you need to release the port which is assigned to it

Comment: Please shutdown the system and hold for 5 mins. after restart it

Comment: Bind exceptions can also happen when the hostname cannot be resolved properly. Have you changed your hostname recently? If not, it is likely that there is still some other process bound to the port that GlassFish needs as @BhaskaraArani says. Try using the command `sudo netstat -lntp` to list all listening TCP ports and the processes that are bound to them. Look for any Java processes.